# Another why won't my jquery ajax work in ie question

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Just want to make sure my test code below is proper. I've been reading and it seems html syntax errors renders the jquery ajax unusable in ie?

There are a bunch of includes where this code resides, so is it possible there is something wrong in one of those files, having nothing to do with my ajax code?

```
$("#checkEmail").blur(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "adamcheck.php",
    data: "checkit=" + $("#checkEmail").val(),
    success: function(output){
      $("#userCheck").html(output);
    }
  });                                                           
});
```

adamcheck.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("FGHFGHGFH");
});
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkit'])){      
  $email= $_POST['checkit'];      
  echo "<p>$email</p>";
}       
?>
```

Comment: @adam , do one thing , if you have firefox and firebug installed , open firebug and then open net panel , see if your ajax call is getting fired or not?? this is best way to start debugging.

Comment: Do you have the `id `"checkEmail"` used multiple times in the page?

Comment: userCheck is the <span id="userCheck"></span> where everything is displayed... checkEmail is used once.

Comment: what HTML errors do you get on HTML validation? Javascript errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way in such a situation (where you have doubts on many things) is to debug step by step, entity by entity. First clear your doubt on the AJAX post. Take only this code and the necessary minimum HTML and php code, put them in a separate setup (separate from your project). There is no shortcut to this.

If this works, then move on to the bunch of includes. There

By the way, your AJAX post code looks syntactically correct and it is a very basic and simple.

Comment: Thanks. Yea i ended up doing it and it was an include... luckily it does not seem like an essential js file

Comment: you are welcome. was there a js error due to that other file?